# receiving weird facebook user id's

Tags: php, facebook

When my app starts I get the user's facebook id. This works fine for some people, but when other people get on I get weird id's. In particular the id starts with 10000. I can't figure out why I'm getting this kind of id for some people and not for others. 
Would this be caused by a mistake in how I'm getting the id?

Comment: Post your code, your question is vague

Comment: this is ok. there is not any problem since the facebook has the ton of users so its normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has **a lot** of users.  They can assign user id's in 64bit numbers.  That is what you are seeing with those "different" ids. In order to allow everyone to be able to use these 64bit numbers even if they don't have a 64bit system, Facebook returns these values as strings.

You need to store your `user_id` values as strings.  This will prevent numbers getting too big to hold as `int` values.  In my experience, the best thing to do is store your user id values as `varchar` - this will also minimize problems with possible changes in the future.

We don't actually perform any mathematical operations on user_id values, so there is no need to store it as a number.

Comment: My question was pretty vague, but this answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's perfectly normal.

Sorry for the short response, but it's /that/ simple.

**Edit**

Those kinds of IDs are valid.